# How to Open this file structure as Flex project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I received a Flex project but don't know how to open it in Flash builder. It doesn't contain a project.mxml or .actionScriptProperties, .flexProperties and .project files.

the file structure looks like this:

```
(rootFolder)
    -(com)
        ...subfoldrestructure containing only folders and .as files
    -(src)
        -(_embed)
            -assets.fla
            -assets.swf
            -assets.swc
        -Main-app.xml
        -Main.as
        -icon-16.png
        ...
        -icon-128.png
```

how do I make a compilable Flex project out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a Flex project, that's a Flash project.  Just create a new Actionscript project and point the location of it at the same location as this one.  It will add the necessary project files to compile.  It will try to create another Main actionscript file, but you can delete the one that it made and select the one already there as the default application.

Comment: thank you! what exactly is the difference between an ActionScript project and a Flex Project? after my understanding Flex is just a ActionScript class library, no?

Comment: No, Flex is a UI framework that uses mxml (xml based) to create RIAs in a very quick and easy way.  It also has a component library that can be easily used, modified and skinned for our uses.  It works on top of Flash (uses actionscript and all that), but is different in the way we develop them.